# Getting min value of two MySQL tables

Tags: php, mysql

I've got stuck at joining two tables and fetching the min value of a price.

I have two tables "tb1" and "tb2".
Both includes ean, price and some other columns.

I wan't to get the cheapest price for same ean's.

So I got this left join:

```
SELECT price,* FROM tb1 as w left join tb2 as e on w.ean=e.ean
```

But how do I get the cheapest price?
I know MIN() but the problem is, the min price could be in tb1 or tb2...

Hope you could help me :)

Regards :)

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following solution using a sub-select with [`UNION ALL`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/union.html) to merge the tables into one (`tbAll`):

```
 SELECT ean, MIN(price) FROM (
     SELECT ean, price FROM tb1
     UNION ALL
     SELECT ean, price FROM tb2
 ) tbAll
 GROUP BY ean
```

... or another solution using the `LEFT JOIN`:

```
 SELECT w.ean, MIN(LEAST(w.price, e.price)) 
 FROM tb1 AS w LEFT JOIN tb2 AS e ON w.ean = e.ean
 GROUP BY w.ean
```

In case you need additional information, you can use the [`UNION ALL`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/union.html) solution with additional [`ROW_NUMBER`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_row-number) (available since MySQL 8.0):

```
SELECT t.ean, t.price, t.merchant FROM (
    SELECT ean, price, merchant, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ean ORDER BY ean, price) AS rn 
    FROM (
        SELECT ean, price, merchant FROM tb1
        UNION ALL
        SELECT ean, price, merchant FROM tb2
    ) tbAll
)t WHERE t.rn = 1
```

... or in case you are using a MySQL version earlier 8.0 you can use the following:

```
SELECT t.ean, t.price, t.merchant FROM (
    SELECT ean, price, merchant, IF(@prev <> ean, @rn:=0, @rn), @prev:=ean, @rn:=@rn+1 AS rn 
    FROM (
        SELECT ean, price, merchant FROM tb1
        UNION ALL
        SELECT ean, price, merchant FROM tb2
        ORDER BY ean, price
    ) tbAll JOIN (SELECT @rn:=0) init_rn JOIN (SELECT @prev:='') init_prev
)t WHERE t.rn = 1
```

[**demo on dbfiddle.uk**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=16129116976593175481ad923bf56913)

Comment: working perfectly. I used the first code from you. its an easy way.
I got one little question, the tables both includes a column called "merchant".
The price is from each merchant, how I can get the matching merchant to my price?

Answer (score 0):

Use Case

```
   CASE
     WHEN w.price < e.price THEN w.price
     ELSE e.price
   END AS MINPRICE
```